# Store the contents of text file in return variable and manipulate wherever required in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below function & I am trying to get/store the contents of text file in another temp file(removing unnecessary line) with appending special character.
But I also want the same content which is in temp text file with different special character next time but I am not able to do that.Below function is creating a temp file.To get desired output I need to create file every time with same function again which is not good way.Is there anything we can do without creating a temp/extra file and store the contents in return variable and append the special character whatever we want multiple times

```
import os
import re

def mainfest():
    pathfile = "abc_12.txt"
    with open(pathfile, 'r') as firstfile, open('tmp.txt', 'r') as s:
         for line in firstfile:
             if line.strip().startswith("-") or line.startswith("<"):
                print"ignore")
             elif re.search('\\S', line):
                name = str(os.path.basename(line))
                s.write("*" +fname) 


def contents():
    temppath = "temp.txt"
    with open(temp path, 'r') as f:
         lines = f.readlines()
         lines+= lines 
         return lines   


manifest()
value = contents()
```

file **abc_12.txt**

```
---ABC-123

nice/abc.py
xml/abc.py

<<NOP-123
bac\nice.py
abc.py

---CDEF-345
jkl.oy
abc.py
```

I want the contents of abc_12.txt file I can get in return something like that

```
abc.py
abc.py
nice.py
abc.py
jkl.oy
abc.py
```

and manipulate them wherever I want similar to below output

**Output 1:**

```
* abc.py
* abc.py
* nice.py
* abc.py
* jkl.oy
* abc.py
```

**Output 2:**

```
@@abc.py
@@abc.py
@@nice.py
@@abc.py
@@jkl.oy
@@abc.py
```

Comment: I really do not understand your question at all, but I suspect you might be looking for **StringIO** to hold contents of files... https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO

Comment: @MarkSetchell edit the question.Hope this clears

Comment: maybe first read file and create list with all data and later write it in temp file - and later you can use this list to create other file. OR use some list `result = []` and `result.append(name)` and later use `return result`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe first you should read file, search names and keep on list

```
def read_data():
    results = []
   
    with open("abc_12.txt") as infile:
         for line in infile:
             if line.strip().startswith(("-", "<")):  # `startswith`/`endswith` can use tuple 
                print("ignore:", line)
             elif re.search('\\S', line):
                name = os.path.basename(line)
                results.append(name)

    return results
```

And later you can use this list to create temp file or other file

```
data = read_data()

with open('temp.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in data:
        outfile.write(f'* {line}')
        #print(f'* {line}', end='')
        
with open('other.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in data:
        outfile.write(f'@@{line}')
        #print(f'@@{line}', end='')
```

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code.

I used `io.StringIO` only to simulate file in memory - so everyone can simply copy and test it.

```
import os
import re
import io

text = r'''---ABC-123

nice/abc.py
xml/abc.py

<<NOP-123
bac\nice.py
abc.py

---CDEF-345
jkl.oy
abc.py
'''

def read_data():
    results = []
   
    with io.StringIO(text) as infile:
    #with open("abc_12.txt") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip()
            if line:
                if line.startswith(("-", "<")):  # `startswith`/`endswith` can use tuple 
                    print("ignore:", line)
                else:
                    name = os.path.basename(line)
                    results.append(name)

    return results

data = read_data()

with open('temp.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in data:
        outfile.write(f'* {line}\n')
        print(f'* {line}')
        
with open('other.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in data:
        outfile.write(f'@@{line}\n')
        print(f'@@{line}')
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to save in file then you still need `for`-loop to create string

```
data = read_data()

string_1 = ''
for line in data:
    string_1 += f'* {line}\n'
        
string_2 = ''
for line in data:
    string_2 += f'@@{line}\n'
```

or to create new list (and eventually string)

```
data = read_data()

list_1 = []
for line in data:
    list_1.append(f'* {line}')
        
list_2 = []
for line in data:
    list_2.append(f'@@{line}')

string_1 = "\n".join(list_1)
string_2 = "\n".join(list_2)
```

Comment: Is this possible without creating these files?To store the output in variable results and manipulate for e.g a = " *"+results and next time b = "@@".results

Comment: you need `for`-loop with `result = result + " *" + line "\n"` or with `new_list.append(" *" + line)`. See new code in answer.